# Select directive not selecting option when options are loaded asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `<select>` directive whose options are loaded asynchronously. The variable that the `ng-model` attribute points to exists prior to the options being loaded. However, after the options are loaded the correct option is not selected. Instead, the select becomes blank. I've created a plunk to demonstrate this behaviour: http://plnkr.co/edit/KNunC6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9714#ref-pullrequest-53337829

seems like this is an angular core bug. you'd be more successful using `ng-repeat` and `ng-checked` I guess.

Comment: Thanks, i'm gonna have to keep up with that issue. I've switched to using `ng-repeat` for now - luckily my option list is pretty small so the extra scope overhead is not noticeable. Just a tiny typo though, `ng-checked` should be `ng-selected`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this fixes your issue. Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWMp7S3xHQzJAuUCv9Sy?p=preview). The problem was that you were initializing the `ngModel` before the promise was finished. The `ngModel` needs to be initialized after the list gets populated so angular can figure out which `option` is `selected`. Also, the `ngOptions` is tricky sometimes because angular assigns a unique id to every `option` and ignores the `value` attribute. I had this issue a couple of times also, nasty one!

Comment: This works however i ended up using @zwacky's answer because it was easier to refactor the template vs. the control flow in my controller. Good call on staying away from `ngOptions` until it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem when the value part of the option has the same value as the label part.

In your case, value == id == 'Canada' and label == name == 'Canada' as well. If you change one of them to anything else, it will work. I am not sure why it is an issue, but just change and it will be ok.

Example: change the name from 'Canada' to 'Canada ':

```
[
    { id: 'Canada', name: 'Canada ' }, 
    { id: 'US', name: 'United States of America' }
]
```